# Failed to load wp-admin/admin-ajax.php:1 resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) in Wordpress Ajax Call

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Main Plugin File Code is:

```
wp_register_script('insertrating', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/dataInsertJ.js', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_localize_script( 'insertrating', 'insertrating_ajax', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) );
wp_enqueue_script("insertrating");
```

Code For DataInsertJ.js is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#one').click(function(e) {  
        var postid = jQuery('#tihom-rating-post-id').val();
        jQuery.ajax
        ({ 
            url: insertrating_ajax.ajax_url,
            data: {
                "postid": postid, 
                "rating": 1
            },
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result)
            {
            
            },
            error: function( error ){
                console.log("error");
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });

});
```

I am getting an error "Failed to load wp-admin/admin-ajax.php:1 resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress admin-ajax.php 400 bad request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48025825/wordpress-admin-ajax-php-400-bad-request)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue: as i need to add "action : 'some_action'" in "data"