# Trying to get access to admin-ajax.php but failing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, roots-sage

I’m having some trouble getting access to admin-ajax.php via admin_url and I get 400 Bad Request every time. Have looked at some posts in this forum but still can’t get why it’s not working.

My setup.php looks like this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {

wp_enqueue_style('sage/main.css', asset_path('styles/main.css'), false, null);
wp_enqueue_script('sage/main.js', asset_path('scripts/main.js'), ['jquery'], null, true);
wp_enqueue_script('sage/ajax-pagination', asset_path('scripts/ajax-pagination.js'), ['jquery'], null, true);

wp_localize_script( 'sage/ajax-pagination', 'sage', array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
));
if (is_single() && comments_open() && get_option('thread_comments')) {
    wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
}

}, 100);
```

And then I have added an ajax.js script which I will use and it looks like this:

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.nav-links a', function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: window.sage.ajax_url,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      action: 'ajax_pagination'
    },
    success: function( result ) {
      alert( result );
    }
  })
})
```

So whenever I click the .nav_link I only get a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) from localhost:3000/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.

Does anyone have any idea what I’m doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress admin-ajax.php 400 bad request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48025825/wordpress-admin-ajax-php-400-bad-request)

Comment: Sorry no, my problem is that I can't access admin-ajax at all

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a 400 (Bad Request) is beacause you are not adding 'nonce' in your ajax call.

> When the console says "*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) from localhost:3000/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.*" it means it wasn't able to fetch the result back from the server. You are missing nonce which is very is necessary to fo the ajax request. Learn more about it [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces):

Your code should look like this.

```
wp_localize_script( 'sage/ajax-pagination', 'sage', array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce')
));
```

and in your JS file.

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.nav-links a', function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: window.sage.ajax_url,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      action: 'ajax_pagination',
      nonce: window.sage.nonce,
    },
    success: function( result ) {
      alert( result );
    }
  })
})
```