# Update shortcode values using ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, shortcode

I'm having a problem with a calendar.
I've made a shortcode which returns events link in a grid that shows the current month view.
Then I set $month_index in order to navigate through months (default is 0 so it shows the current month; it shows the next month when $month_index = 1 and so on).
The function agenda_script() should pass the $month_index value to Agenda_fn() in order to update the shortcode output.
I don't know why I get error 400 for admin-ajax.php, I've checked [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48025825/wordpress-admin-ajax-php-400-bad-request) but I can't understand how to fix my code because it seems too different from my case
can anyone help me?
thanks in advance

```
$month_index = 0;
function Agenda_fn($atts) {
    global $month_index;
    ob_start();?>
    <button id="dec_month_index">&lt;</button>
    <button id="inc_month_index">&gt;</button>
    [...]
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('Agenda', 'Agenda_fn');
```

```
function agenda_script() {
    if(is_page(4037)){?>
        <script>
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $('#dec_month_index').on('click', function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: ajaxurl,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {action: 'dec_month_index',},
                            success: function(response) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: ajaxurl,
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: {
                                    action: 'Agenda',
                                    atts: response
                                }
                            });
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    });
                });
                $('#inc_month_index').on('click', function() {...}
            });
        });
        </script><?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'agenda_script');
```

```
function dec_month_index() {
    global $month_index;
    $month_index--;
    echo $month_index;
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_dec_month_index', 'dec_month_index');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_dec_month_index', 'dec_month_index');
```

Comment: Please check your server's error log for more details. Seing that error helps to check where the problem really occured. Afterwards, please check whether this is a JS problem or a PHP problem

Comment: Wrapping `jQuery(document).ready` into `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'` makes little sense to begin with. (Not the reason of your problem, but pretty senseless nonetheless.)

Comment: _Which_ AJAX request are you actually getting the 400 response for, you are making two of them there? I suppose it will be the second, "inner" one - you specify `action: 'Agenda'` there, so for that to work, you would have to have also set up AJAX endpoints `wp_ajax_Agenda` / `wp_ajax_nopriv_Agenda` ... which I doubt you actually did?

Comment: thanks @NicoHaase, @CBroe  
After setting endpoints `add_action('wp_ajax_Agenda', 'Agenda_fn')` / `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_Agenda', 'Agenda_fn')` (which I forgot to include) server log reports two '200' response (access) to admin-ajax.php, then the `Agenda_fn` is executed.  
After that, I've checked the value of `$month_index` before return `ob_get_clean();` and I've seen that the value is the same when loading the page or clicking the buttons.  
I guess that this means that the ajax action `Agenda` do not pass the _response_ to the function `Agenda_fn($atts)` correctly.  
thanks again