Wordpress admin-ajax.php returns 0 and 400 bad request
I have been working in a project and I hit a road block from admin-ajax.php file, when i make an ajax request it returns 400 error bad request and the admin-ajax.php response in the network tab is 0.
script.js

        $.ajax({
            url: city_generator.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                nonce: city_generator.nonce,
                action: 'load_counties',
                state: state,
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('County response:', response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.error('Error loading counties:', error);
            },
        });

and inside my admin-page.php
/ Example: Load counties based on state
    add_action('wp_ajax_load_counties', 'load_counties_callback');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_counties', 'load_counties_callback');


function load_counties_callback() {
    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
    check_ajax_referer('ajax-nonce', 'nonce');  // Verify the nonce
    if (isset($_POST['state'])) {
        $state = sanitize_text_field($_POST['state']);
        $counties = get_counties_by_state($state);
        wp_send_json_success(array('counties' => $counties));
    }
    wp_die();
}


and also in my city-generator.php
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'city_generator_admin_enqueue_scripts');
 function city_generator_admin_enqueue_scripts($hook) {
    if ($hook === 'settings_page_city-generator') {
        wp_enqueue_script('city-generator-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/script.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
        wp_enqueue_style('city-generator-style', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/style.css');
        wp_localize_script('city-generator-script', 'city_generator', array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce'),
        ));
    }
}

and the error I get in the console is
load-scripts.php?c=1…e,utils&ver=6.5.2:2 
 POST http://localhost/mywordpress/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)
script.js:26 Error loading counties: 
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort
: 
ƒ (e)
always
: 
ƒ ()
catch
: 
ƒ (e)
complete
: 
ƒ ()
done
: 
ƒ ()
error
: 
ƒ ()
fail
: 
ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders
: 
ƒ ()
getResponseHeader
: 
ƒ (e)
overrideMimeType
: 
ƒ (e)
pipe
: 
ƒ ()
progress
: 
ƒ ()
promise
: 
ƒ (e)
readyState
: 
4
responseText
: 
"0"
setRequestHeader
: 
ƒ (e,t)
state
: 
ƒ ()
status
: 
400
statusCode
: 
ƒ (e)
statusText
: 
"Bad Request"
success
: 
ƒ ()
then
: 
ƒ (t,n,r)
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

please help. Thank you

Error 400 is a bad request. You should not upload images of code/data/errors but expand the error and post that. The 'Network' tab is better to provide both the message sent as well as the error received. Based on the URL you have WordPress installed locally. What is WordPress / the web server logging to disk when you make the request?

http://localhost/mywordpress/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Why did you post the URL?

I thought that was what you meant, I didn't fully grasp it

"What is WordPress / the web server logging to disk when you make the request?"

Maybe. That return code is 200, which means that it's working. You said you were getting a 400. Is it fixed now? There should be more details if a 400 is generated. You can put these in your question. Also, please make the console output readable.

::1 - - [04/May/2024:19:35:03 +0100] "POST /mywordpress/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 400 1 "http://localhost/mywordpress/wordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=city-generator" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

Actually, is the answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48025825/wordpress-admin-ajax-php-400-bad-request?rq=2

i posted the wrong one sorry, this is the log

I've checked it out, I was a bit cautious about that kind of error and avoided it

A Google search tells me that 400 errors are logged into WordPress' debug.log file. Look there first. Next, if needed, post the complete XHR request you copied from the Network tab in the browser. Is it correct? Next, add some debug logs to your city-generator function. Is the function being called? Is the data you are getting what you expect?
